# understand azure standard disk IOPS

Tags: azure

Hi have 8x4TB disks attached to Standard_DS14_v2, I am getting very low IOPS and server getting hung. I am using this server as a commvault backup media agent server.

Could you please help me how many IOPS i will get if i use these disk individually like each disk with seperate drive letter.

How many IOPS i will get if i create a storage pool with all 8 disks and use as a single drive letter.

i want to understand between storage pool performance and individual disk IOPS.